# JS Bin while infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jsbin

I noticed strange behaviour of JS Bin runner when I execute the following code:

```
var ask = prompt("test");

while(ask!=="yes"){
    ask = prompt("test");
}
```

I get this kind of error:

> Exiting potential infinite loop at line 4. To disable loop protection:
>   add "// noprotect" to your code

I was wandering why is that happening ? (The execution of that code works fine in site code)

Comment: It says potential because unless you answer yes, it will be an infinite loop. Don't worry too much about JSBin, personally I never use it.

Comment: Yeach, I know, but because of that it completely blocks my code from  execution

Comment: Run it on JSFiddle or just add `//noprotect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an unsolvable problem in computer science called [The Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

In short, it means that a computer cannot look at a piece of code and figure out if it will go into an endless loop or end at some time.  However, they can make some *guesses* about it and warn you if they spot anything that *might be* dangerous.

Not *is*.  *Might be.*

This is one of those cases.  The system is warning you and you have to say "Yea, yea, I heard you. Do it anyways."[*]

[*] This, of course, is to prepare us for a Star-Trek Universe where we disable the safety on everything to save the day.

Answer (score 1):

**prompt, alert, confirm**.

These JS functions are synchronous, that means browser will stop doing anything and will hold/wait for the user response. Since you also possibly created a infinite loop by prompting again by checking the result of previous prompt, it throws that message.

This infinite loop will make the browser nonresponsive