# prompt only loops once

Tags: javascript, while-loop, prompt

I'm learning javascript. I was trying to make a loop that keeps prompting the user for activities which then gets stored in an array. If the user inputs 'DONE' it stops asking for inputs.

The problem is, after it runs once, the loop ends even though the while condition isn't met.

I am using jsbin as a sandbox to practice js. Here is the code:

```
var todoList = [];
while (input != "DONE") {
var input = prompt("Please enter an activity. When you are done type 'DONE'.");
todoList.push(input);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Loops multiple times for me....

Comment: Try putting var input outside the while loop

Comment: Works fine for me in chrome. Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/yewipab/edit?js,console  I have tried using jsfiddle. They don't have a console on there. So I stick with jsbin.

Answer (score 1):

Your input variable is only inside your loop. Initialise it, before the loop with `var input = "";`.

Then remove `var` from the loop (as you're assigning a value to the existing variable), it should work ok.

```
var todoList = [];
var input = "";
while (input != "DONE") {
  input = prompt("Please enter an activity. When you are done type 'DONE'.");
  todoList.push(input);
}
```

Comment: ran this in jsbin, the same problem still occurs.http://jsbin.com/yewipab/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

Var needs to be outside the loop.

```
var input;
var todoList = [];
while (input != "DONE") {
     input = prompt("Please enter an activity. When you are done type 'DONE'.");
     todoList.push(input);
}
```

Comment: This will only prompt the user once, and will result in an infinite loop (unless they enter 'done')

Comment: Yes, but it'll only ask them for the input once as the prompt isn't in the loop

Answer (score 0):

@Afixoftrix your code is working fine in browser  console and js fiddle .JsBin have some protection for infinite loop.see it in console.if you need to study javascript,dont learn it in thirdparty tool,use code editor or browser console which help to get more knowledge about javascript.[image]

See more:[JS Bin while infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448485/js-bin-while-infinite-loop)

Js fiddle consolelog:[image]

Answer (score 0):

We should able to handle upper and lowercase letters.

```
var res, input = "";
var todoList  = [];
while (res !== "DONE") {
 if (input != "" && input != null) {
   todoList.push(input);
 }
  input = prompt("Please enter an activity. When you are done type 'DONE'.");
  if (input !== null) {
   res = input.toUpperCase();
  }
}
console.log(todoList);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hke9om5a/5/)